# disable csrf protection in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, cross-browser, csrf

I developed a web application which was released into production and which has a link in the intranet of the company.Now they are trying to get it to the mobile devices ,but the intranet team came back telling me to disable the CSRF protection as the application is used only inside the company and so there is no huge risk.
So how should i do that? PLease help.
My application is developed using c#,asp.net,sql,javascript,ajax

Thanks

Comment: Your intranet team is **wrong**.  Don't do that!

Comment: I agree, unless there is actually a real problem with it its a bad idea

Comment: @DanielPowell: Even if there is a real problem, it's still a bad idea.  Intranet sites are just as vulnerable to CSRF as other websites.  (probably more so due to weaker auth)

Comment: i personally agree with all your comments,but i think i have to disable it some how as the intranet team is still stuck on that.Is there any way ?